# reset the textbox on specific value of dropdown (in HandleChange()) in Redux form

Tags: react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

How to reset a textbox when another dropdown field is changed in redux-form?
I tried using `dispatch(change())` syntax but I keep getting the following error:

> redux-form/lib/change could not be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution for above problem. The

> redux-form/lib/change could not be resolved

error got resolved when I removed the `import {change} from 'redux-form'` statement. Instead now, I am passing the `change` from the form's props.
To dynamically reset the value of `Field` following statement worked like charm:

```
dispatch(actions.change('FormName', 'FieldName', ''));
```

**Note**: Below code did not work for me:

```
dispatch(change('FormName', 'FieldName', ''));
```